# How to change the width of ng-fullcalendar

Tags: angular, fullcalendar, angular5, angular-calendar

I would like to manually change the width and the height. I can change the height and the aspect ratio in the calendar options:

```
this.options = {
  height:700,
  aspectRatio:1.5}
```

But, I don't know how to change the width of the calendar

I also tried to put this in the CSS file:

```
.ng-fullcalendar{
   width:50%;
   margin-left: 300px;
 }
```

But it didn't change anything.

EDIT:

Here is a stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-fullcalendar-demo?file=app%2Fapp.component.css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

create new custom class

I have create a demo on **[Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-fullcalendar-demo-sr4vho?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

```
.my-ng-fullcalendar{
   width:50%;
   margin-left: 300px;
 }



<div *ngIf="calendarOptions" class="my-ng-fullcalendar">
    <ng-fullcalendar #ucCalendar [options]="calendarOptions" (eventClick)="eventClick($event.detail)" (eventDrop)="updateEvent($event.detail)"
        (eventResize)="updateEvent($event.detail)" (clickButton)="clickButton($event.detail)"></ng-fullcalendar>
</div>
```

Comment: Do you know how I can make this change only for desktop screen and for any other screen the width is 100% and no margins ?

Comment: Yes,You can use media css.

Comment: You can use 

import { NgZone } from '@angular/core';

// Inject NgZone in your constructor:    
constructor(private zone: NgZone) {

}

// Run the code that changes state inside the zone
matchMedia('(max-width: 400px)').addListener((mql => {
    if (mql.matches) {
        this.zone.run(() => {
            this.myclass = 'toggled';
        });
    }
}));

Answer (score 1):

after finding the width property in module, you can add this property:

for example:

```
.ng-fullcalendar {
   width: 50% !important;
   margin-left: 300px !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried that it didn't work. You can try here https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-fullcalendar-demo?file=app%2Fapp.component.css

Comment: Never use !important  - it breaks styles priority. If you can't change styles with .css (and your selector is 100% correct) it means that you either have to provide a more specific rule or change attribute with JS.

Answer (score 1):

You can apply css style to the div containing the calendar

```
<div style="width:50%"><ng-fullcalendar></ng-fullcalendar></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `ng-fullcalendar` class in the component. You have to apply the styles to the element. You can see the demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-fullcalendar-demo-n6wnbs).

Basically you have to apply the following styles.

```
ng-fullcalendar {
    position: absolute;
    width: 50%;
    margin-left: 300px;
}
```